# Calling a shellscript from php - not working correctly

Tags: php, linux, shell

I am calling a shellscript from php using shell_exec() command. Following is the simple version of the shell script:

```
args[0] = "tom"
echo "hello"
echo "${args[0]}"
```

When I run this script from terminal, it gives the following output in terminal:

```
hello
tom
```

Whereas when I call this from php using shell_exec() only  "hello" is printed and not "tom" . ie; variable assignment is not working when the script is called from php. Why this happens and how can I resolve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably PHP executes the script with `sh`, not Bash; thus arrays (which are a Bash feature) are not supported by the shell.

Workarounds: don't use arrays, or explicitly inboke Bash on the script. (If PHP understands shebangs, having a correct shebang line as the first line of the script may well be sufficient.)

Comment: shell_exec("path/to/file.sh") is how we call the script, which means we are executing this as sh, correct?

Comment: Again, adding a proper shebang may be enough to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First, `args[0] = "tom"` should not have space. It should be `args[0]="tom"`
(I'm not sure is this the problem, but  worth to try).

Try this at the end of your code, to see which shell is running your script.

```
echo "`ps -p $$`"
```

Try both on terminal and PHP scripts to see if it same shell or not.